# MongoDB querying by sub-document value not working as expected

Tags: mongodb

I have two schemas, a `Profile` and a `LevelOfNeed`.

```
Profile
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d35960a695dfa140137fca"),
    . . .
    "levelOfNeedServiced" : ObjectId("56d35828a695dfa140137fc7")
}

Level of Need
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d35828a695dfa140137fc7"),
    "sortOrder" : 2,
    "description" : "Moderate Needs",
    "additionalCost" : 3,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I currently have 4 documents for `LevelOfNeed`. What I need to do is select all of the `Profile` documents where the `levelOfNeedServiced.sortOrder` is `>=` a value.

Example:

```
db.getCollection('profiles').find({
    'levelOfNeedServiced.sortOrder': { $gte: 2 }
})
```

Given my data, I would expect to see the example `Profile`, but this returns no results. What am I doing wrong?

---

### Update 1

Previously, I was running MongoDB 3.0.9. I've since upgraded to 3.2.3, however I'm still getting the same results. According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#field-in-embedded-document-equals-a-value), I should be able to query on an embedded document field value.

---

### Update 2

The aggregate function solution works as expected, but since I already had an array of `LevelOfNeed` objects, I was able to use that to get to the related documents I needed using the `$in` operator.

Comment: Mongodb does not resolve references for you in whatever versions till now. But they do provide the lookup aggregation operator to make joins with other collections in 3.2. You can use it to join and then match the documents. The link you have pasted does not resolve references.

Comment: Moreover the field levelofneedserviced is not a embedded document but a field whose value is an objectid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately mongodb does not support joins until version 3.2. In version 3.2 it provides the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation operator to lookup referenced documents across collections.

You could use it as below:

```
db.Profile.aggregate([
{
  $lookup:{
           "from":"LevelOfNeed",
           "localField":"levelOfNeedServiced",
           "foreignField":"_id",
           "as":"joined"
          }
},
{
  $match:{
          "joined.sortOrder":{$gte:2}
         }
},
{
  $project:{"levelOfNeedServiced":1,...} //include things you want to project.
}
])
```

Your code:

```
db.getCollection('profiles').find({
    'levelOfNeedServiced.sortOrder': { $gte: 2 }
})
```

does not work as intended because, the field `levelOfNeedServiced` is identified as a field containing an `ObjectId` and not the resolved `LevelOfNeed` document.

Comment: Doh - how could I not have noticed the version in documentation was 3.2. Let me upgrade to 3.2 and re-run my queries. If it works, I'll +1 and accept your answer. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Ok, so I've upgraded to 3.2.3, and according to the docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#field-in-embedded-document-equals-a-value I should be able to execute my original query, but I'm still getting an empty result set :(

Comment: In 3.2 you get the capability of the lookup operator. You still cannot resolve references in a find query.

Comment: I was able to get your aggregate query working as expected, but ended up using a different solution to get to the related `LevelOfNeed` documents which I'll add to my question. Thank you though, I have a better understanding of what's going on now.